# Heroku does not seem to add my admin static files to static_root

Tags: django, heroku

This is my settings file:

```
import os
import logging
import logging.config
import sys


import django_heroku


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'this is not my secret key'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
# DJANGO_DEBUG must be 'true' (any case) to turn on debugging
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', '').lower() == 'true'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '*'
]


# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb'
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True


# Static files
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

django_heroku.settings(locals(), staticfiles=False)


LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': sys.stdout,
        }
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO'
    }
}
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True
```

`heroku local` seems to serve the static files correctly (django admin is nicely styled. However, when deployed, the static files do not seem to be there.

I ran `python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear` using `heroku run` which states that 121 static files have been copied (I only made two custom ones, so it seems it is saying the admin static files were copied). However running `heroku run ls staticfiles` it shows only my two files, and nothing else.

I subsequently managed to run `python manage.py collectstatic` seemingly successfully (there are now files in `./staticfiles/admin`). However, when I visit the url (domain/static/admin/css/login.css for example), the file is not found.

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You've specifically disabled the static files handling in your call to `django_heroku.settimgs`, so they won't be collected or served. Remove that argument.

The reason you don't see anything after running collectstatic yourself is that each command is run in its own dyno, and through filesystem is not shared between dynos; changes made by one command will not be seen in a subsequent one.